# When an android runs out of battery does it keep open the tabs that were being used?

Tags: battery

It must be a stupid question but it’s important. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this something mere experimentation could ascertain? Try it out, self-answer, then accept the answer for the reputation.

Comment: Which tabs do you mean ?  The browser?  If so, which Browser?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm afraid this question is unclear about the "open tabs being used". While we might strongly assume that you're referring to browser tabs, there may be other apps/features that use tabs. A little more clarification by [edit]ing would help, thanks!

Comment: Keeping tabs opened is a feature of the app/browser, not of Android.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean web pages in the browser?

If the device closed down properly when it ran low on power, it should have made a record of which pages it had open, and the browser should reload them when the device has been charged and you re-launch the browser. However, there are significant caveats to that:

- The exact behaviour can depend on which browser you were using.
- Anything you set up on web pages, but didn't submit to the web server, is likely to have been lost.
- If you were logged into a web page, the server might have logged you out, or done other things, while you were inactive.
- If the device didn't close down properly when it ran out of power, it's hard to guess what would happen.

So the answer to the question you asked is "It depends." A lot more detail, starting with the device model, Android version and browser name, may let us be more specific.